# How to get selected option values from multiselects drop down using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

i wanted to select selected values from multiselect drop down [See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmCSh/10/)

i tried some way but not getting , can some one help me out of this problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({ 

        click: function(e){

        var abc =  $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked");

        console.log(abc);
    }   
});

});
</script>
</head>

<h3>Basic</h3>
<p>
    <select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
    <option value="option11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="option12">Option 12</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget#retrieve-all-selected-values-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code to get selected item

```
   <script>
    $( "select" )
      .change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $( this ).text() + " ";
        });
        $( "div" ).text( str ); // Put selected value to div
        console.log(str);
      })
      .trigger( "change" );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

try the following

```
 $("#examplea").on("click", function(){
            $("#examplea option:selected").each(function(){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

first assign id to select tag say basic_example
Use this in Javascript:

```
  if($('#basic_example').is(":checked"))
{
    var temp=($('#basic_example').serialize());
    alert(temp);
}
```

Hopefully this works

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").multiselect({
            close: function() {
                debugger;
                var values = new Array();
                $(this).multiselect("getChecked").each(function(index, item) {
                    values.push($(item).val());
                });
                $("input[id*=selectedValues]").val(values.join(","));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```